# How do I tell if a root CA is in place for a particular SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl

I have [another question](https://serverfault.com/questions/582385/what-does-it-mean-that-no-cert-given-is-a-domain-name-certificate) where I ask about an SSL problem I'm having. One commenter asked, "Are the root CA and intermediate CA also in place?"

I understand that CA stands for Certificate Authority, and I have a vague understanding of what a root CA and intermediate CA are. What I'm totally clueless about is how I can tell for sure if the root CA (and intermediate CA) are in place. How can I tell?

Comment: SSL Shopper have a test utility here - http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html - you put in your website address, and it checks the SSL certificate chain and says if it's setup properly or not, and where it's broken.

Answer (score 0):

In Apache2 configuration certificates are installed with these directives:

`SSLCertificateKeyFile` - Private key for certificate
`SSLCertificateFile` - Server certificate file
`SSLCertificateChainFile` - Intermediate and root certificate chain file.

If you use the two first ones and don't have the last one defined, you don't have root / intermediate CAs installed.

If your certificate is installed using `SSLCACertificateFile` directive, then your server certificate and intermediate / root certificates must be concatenated into the file specified in the directive.

In nginx, the `ssl_certificate` directive should contain the file name containing a concatenated list of server certificate + intermediate / root certificates.

Comment: Hmm. What I've done so far is to purchase a professionally signed SSL certificate from DreamHost, and I can't yet install the certificate on my server (Heroku) due to the problems I'm having. So do these things you're mentioning still apply?

Comment: Yes. You need to check with Heroku in what format it needs the certificate in order for it to contain all the needed certificates. You can get the root / intermediate certificates from DreamHost.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I did successfully put SSL on a Heroku site once before and I used the format of root certificate concatenated with intermediate certificate. So I think that answers that question. I'm still unclear on the answer to my original question of how to tell whether the root CA is "in place".